# What is the name of form field where XML belongs to when sending an HTTP POST request to post a job using LinkedIn API

Tags: forms, api, http, post, linkedin-api

I am looking into the following page to post a job to LinkedIn using their API:
http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/posting-job

I am given a sample XML message (as shown below) and a URL to direct HTTP POST request to. However, one thing is not clear to me which HTML form field I will insert XML content to? In other words, what is the name of this FORM field?

URL to direct HTTP POST request to: `http://api.linkedin.com/v1/jobs`

Sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<job>

  <partner-job-id>LIJ-13239292</partner-job-id>

  <contract-id>1234</contract-id>

  <customer-job-code>DE247X</customer-job-code>

  <company>

    <id>1234</id>

    <name>Company ABC</name>

    <description>A great company</description>

  </company>

  <position>

    <title>Chief Architect</title>

    <description>This is a great job.</description>

    <skills-and-experience>Programming, financial analysis, and  thought leadership.</skills-and-experience>

    <location>

      <country>

        <code>us</code>

      </country>

      <postal-code>10012</postal-code>

      <name>Midtown Manhattan</name>

    </location>

    <job-functions>

      <job-function>

        <code>acct</code>

      </job-function>

            <job-function>

              <code>dsgn</code>

            </job-functions>

        </job-functions>

    <industries>

      <industry>

        <code>38</code>

      </industry>

      <industry>

        <code>44</code>

      </industry>

    </industries>

    <job-type>

      <code>C</code>

    </job-type>

    <experience-level>

      <code>4</code>

    </experience-level>

  </position>

  <salary>$100,000-120,000 per year</salary>

  <referral-bonus>$5,000 for employees</referral-bonus>

  <poster>

    <display>true</display>

    <role>

      <code>R</code>

    </role>

        <email-address>user@contract.com</email-address>

  </poster>

  <how-to-apply>

    <application-url>http://www.linkedin.com</application-url>

  </how-to-apply>

  <tracking-pixel-url>http://www.linkedin.com/track.gif</tracking-pixel-url>

</job>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `FORM field`?

Comment: HTML input tag: <input />

Comment: `<form action="http://api.linkedin.com/v1/jobs" method="post">`
 ?